# No effects on size_hint , python, kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I try to change the size_hint of a button in Python, Kivy, but every value i put there the size of the button remain the same.. for the pos is changing but for the size_hint no, and if i change from pos to pos_hint the button is stuck in the corner of the window and from there i cant change nothing... also i tried to stick the pos of the button on a position where is a text in the photo but every time when i resize the kivy window the button and image are changing theyr position.. how i can solve this probelm ?? THANKSSS !!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from random import choice


class MyImage(Image):
    images = ["Q1.png", "Q2.png", "Q3.png"]  # ........

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        correct = Button(pos=(200, 200), size_hint=(.1, .1), on_release=self.random_image, background_color=(1, 1, 1, 0.2))
        self.add_widget(correct)
        self.random_image()

    def random_image(self, *_):
        self.source = choice(self.images)


class RandomQuestionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyImage()


randomApp = RandomQuestionApp()
RandomQuestionApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try size instead of size_hint.

```
correct = Button(
    pos=(200, 200),
    size=(100, 100), 
    on_release=self.random_image, 
    background_color=(1, 1, 1, 0.2)
)
```

> size : This is for static sizing of widgets and takes two arguments
> i.e. (width, height). Default size of the button = (100, 100).

> size_hint : This is for dynamic sizing of the button and provide hint
> of size. It contains two arguments i.e. width and height it can be
> floating values.By default, all widgets have their size_hint=(1, 1).

If there is nothing that influences the button size, your dynamics won't do anything. Size on the other hand would define a fixed size of the button where 100x100 is the default.

Comment: Thanks, is working. But from what I know I don't need to use " hint " to stick the button in  a fix position when i resize the window ? Now when i resize the window the button is changing his position from where i wanted to stay above of a text from the image, but at least i can chage the values :)).

Comment: No, it would be the other way around. You use hint to NOT stick the button in a fixed position but have it adjust depending on the layout.